# Windows Store 10 API

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-store

How can I access the Windows 10 Store? is there any API or RESTful Service to search/details ... for Windows 10 Store Apps?

Thanks
NB: [REST API reference for Windows Store for Business](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt608306(v=vs.85).aspx) is for IT Pro. I need an API to use it within my universal app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to use within your app. You can launch store with searching parameter.

Comment: Now, [Windows Store API available to use within app](http://www.developerinsider.in/2016/03/14/windows-store-analytics-api-now-available/)

Comment: Analytics API is not API he is asking for (search/detail/listing).

Comment: He is mention search/details. If I'm not wrong / means OR not AND

Comment: And also in your app you only need to get your app details. Why anyone need to search API

Comment: There are cases when developers might want to show user their apps on the store. An simple search API call to store will solve it.

The way he mention search OR detail obviously means he want to let user search the store to get a list of apps with detail, consider the link he provide, which describe how to getting OTHER APP's detail. 

Nope, what I want to do in my app is not only limited to get my app details. It only limited by my imagine and store's policy. Dont assume anyone only need something and have no need for other.

Comment: Right, I need it for my app, check Band Store to know why.